# C++ Operator Overloading and Inheritance

Tags: c++, debugging, inheritance, operator-overloading

Am going to start off with the code since it will be easier for me to explain.

```
vector.cpp

template <typename T, unsinged int D>
class Vector
{
public:
    Vector() {}

    inline Vector<T, D> operator+(const Vector<T,D>& r)
    {
        Vector<T,D> result = T(0);
        for(int i = 0; i < D; i++)
            result[i] = (*this)[i] + r[i];

        return result;
    }
private:
    T values[D];
}

template <typename T>
class Vector3 : public Vector<T, 3>
{
   // Initialization constructor etc..
}

main.cpp

int main(int argc, char** args)
{
    Vector3<float> vec1 = Vector3<float>(1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f);
    Vector3<float> vec2 = Vector3<float>(1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f);
    Vector3<float> res;

    res = vec1 + vec2;    // Here's the error

    return 1;
}
```

For some reason I get an error at the indicated line saying, no operator "=" matches these operands, operand types are `Vector3<float> = Vector<float, 3U>`. If I declare variable "res" as `Vector<float, 3> res;` it works. I don't understand why this is happening considering it has inherited the definition from class "Vector". Can somebody please help me out here, and I'd preferably like to make this work without having to re write the operator overloaded functions again for all the derived classes. I have a similar implementation for Matrices as well.

Thank you in advance.

Cheers.

Comment: Base classes cannot be implicitly converted to derived classes.

Comment: Calling object containing fixed-size array `vector` seems confusing.

Comment: Mixing operator overloading and inheritance is almost always a design error.

Comment: why is it almost always a design error?

Answer (score 1):

This `vec1 + vec2` calls the parent classes' `operator+`, which returns an object of the parent class type. You can't assign an object of `Vector<float, 3U>` to an object of type `Vector3<float>`.

```
int main(int argc, char** args)
{
    Vector<float, 3U> v;
    Vector3<float> res;

    res = v;    // Here's the error
}
```

You could do:

```
int main(int argc, char** args)
{
    Vector3<float> vec1 = Vector3<float>(1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f);
    Vector3<float> vec2 = Vector3<float>(1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f);

    Vector<float, 3U> res = vec1 + vec2;
}
```

I would say that trying to use inheritance for this is probably not the best idea. If you can use C++11 then type aliases is probably better:

```
template <typename T, unsinged int D>
class Vector
{
    template<typename... Args> Vector(Args &&...args)
      : values{std::forward<Args>(args)...}
    {}
    // ...
};

template<typename T>
using Vector3 = Vector<T, 3>;
```

---

> i have overloaded '[]', '==' and '!=' and it seems to work without a problem,

The problem is that with `operator+` you are returning the parent type `Vector<float,3U>`, and then trying to use that type where the child type `Vector3<float>` is required.

With `operator[]` you are presumably returning `T&` and then using that where `T&` is required. And with `operator!=` and `operator==` you are returning `bool` and using that where `bool` is required. Do you see the difference? Do you understand why:

```
Vector3<float> res = Vector3<float>();
```

works and

```
Vector3<float> res = Vector<float, 3U>();
```

does not?

> Can you please explain further on what type aliases are, and how it can improve the above implementation, and why it would.

You can read about what they are in [many](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn467695.aspx) [places](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias). The thing that's important about them for your usage is that the do not create a new type, they simply create a new way to refer to a previously declared type.

So, for example, with your inheritance based `Vector3` the code `Vector3<float> res = Vector<float, 3U>();` will fail, but if `Vector3` is a type alias instead:

```
template<typename T> using Vector3 = Vector<T, 3U>;
```

Then the code `Vector3<float> res = Vector<float, 3U>();` will succeed, because there's no longer a mismatch between the types on the left and right sides: Using a type alias means that `Vector3<float>` is not an *inherited* from `Vector<float, 3U>`, it *is* the type `Vector<float, 3U>`.

Comment: i have overloaded '[]', '==' and '!=' and it seems to work without a problem, why are these working, and why does it not work for the arithmetic operations.

Can you please explain further on what type aliases are, and how it can improve the above implementation, and why it would.